# How to get background image from internal css using xpath?

Tags: php, html, css, xpath, domxpath

I want to get background-image URL that is in internal css. I'm using xpath in php

Here is the html structure

```
<div id="plugin-title" class="with-banner">
<div class="vignette"></div>

<style type="text/css">
#plugin-title { width:772px; height:250px; background-size:772px 250px; background-image: url(//ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1279667); }
</style>
<h2 itemprop="name">Jetpack by WordPress.com</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. You can't do it directly with php. But, if you always analyze the same kind of data you can use any REGEX to extract the url of the image. Or you can looking for a powerfull library on the web that will analyze the code & css (if this library exists). Regex = The simplest way is : `preg_match('/background-image: url\((.[^\)]*)\)/sUi', $content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the links for `background-image`, then you can use this RegExp.

```
background-image.*?url\((.*?)\)
```

Example implementation:

```
$html = <<<EOT
<div id="plugin-title" class="with-banner">
    <div class="vignette"></div>
    <style type="text/css">
    #plugin-title { width:772px; height:250px; background-size:772px 250px; background-image: url(//ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1279667); }
    </style>
    <h2 itemprop="name">Jetpack by WordPress.com</h2>
</div>
EOT;

preg_match_all('/background-image.*?url\((.*?)\)/mi', $html, $matches);
```

`$matches` contains all the `background-image` urls.